# What is the proper way to monitor PHP execution in the frontend?

Tags: php, mysql, logging, cron

I will use an example to demonstrate this.

Assuming I have a MySQL DB where I place paths to files to be uploaded to S3, and a status column where each file is attributed either a `pending` or `uploaded` string.

I have a PHP script, `upload.php`, which I can run with `php upload.php` and receive the output logged to my terminal as the script progresses. I would like to set up a cron job that runs the script at certain intervals, say every 30 minutes, where each time the DB is queried and the files which hold a `pending` status are processed for upload.

Now, I want to be able to track the progress of the script, regardless of its current status in the frontend (if currently no pending items are in the DB).

While I would appreciate any specific suggestion on how to do this, my question is also regarding best practice - meaning, what is the **proper** way to do this?

Here's an example of a script of such (it's using the Joshcam [MysqliDb](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class))

```
// Get items with a pending status
function get_items_queue() {
      global $db;
      $cols = Array ("id", "filename");
      $db->where('status = "pending"');
      return $db->get('files', null, $cols);
}

// Upload items to S3
function UploadToS3($filename) {
    if (empty($filename)) {
          return false;
    }

    include_once('/s3/aws-autoloader.php');
    $s3 = new S3Client($somearray); // Some S3 credentials here

    // Print status
    echo $filename . ' is uploading';
    $uploaded = $s3->putObject($somearray); // Uploading to S3

    if ($s3->doesObjectExist($s3_bucket, $filename)) {
          // Print status
          echo $filename . ' was uploaded';
    } else {
          // Print status
          echo 'There has been an issue while uploading ' . $filename;
    }
}

// Run the script
$queue_items = get_items_queue();
foreach ($queue_items as $key => $item) {
      $upload = UploadToS3($item['filename']);
      // Some function here that changes the status column for the uploaded item to 'uploaded'
      if ($upload) {
            set_item_queue_status($item['id']);
      }
}
```

Comment: Track it where?

Comment: Do you want to request the status log of the cron job execution via web?

Comment: A frontend view of a log of some sort (which outputs the echos from the script), or, I was thinking about a jQuery/ajax solution, but I'm not sure if that's the "right way" to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting an installation of [Cronicle](https://github.com/jhuckaby/Cronicle) from jhuckaby.

Essentially a cron manager, but what's most important for my case is the live log-viewer. This enables me to run the script using a cron job at the intervals I defined, and watch as it executes via the log-viewer, while being able to leave and come back at any point to view the currently running task (or any of the previous tasks that ran while I was away).

[image]